# Possible to programmatically enable "show redraw regions" in Flash debug player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Is it possible to enable the "show redraw regions" programmatically? From AS3 code, I mean.

Or is it exclusively a feature of the context menu?

Our current C++ hosting app does not pass through right-clicks and I'd like to avoid changing that code. This is all for testing, doesn't have to be pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, should be able to do it with this line of code:

```
flash.profiler.showRedrawRegions(true)
```

Read the [official docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/profiler/package.html#showRedrawRegions%28%29) for a few more details.